# Java - Replace char using Lambda

Tags: java, lambda

In this code, I am trying to replace all 0s with values from the Map. But it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this using lambdas instead of writing traditional code that loops through each entry and replaces.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "(call SP_PKG.GETINFOTYPE(0, 0, 0, 0))";
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("Param1", "Value1");
    params.put("Param2", "Value2");
    params.put("Param3", "Value3");
    System.out.println("Hello");
    params.forEach((k,v) -> name.replaceFirst("0", v.toString())); 
    System.out.println(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: *But it doesn't work.* Is not an error description. Please explain what it means

Comment: *I am trying to replace all 0s with values*. `replaceFirst` only replaces the first accurence of a String. User replace if you want to replace all.

Answer (score 1):

- first of all you are replacing and not assigning,to get correct replaced string you need to assign to variable after replacement for ex:

> name = name.replaceFirst("0", v.toString());

- and you want to do it inside foreach with lamda expression which will not work in your case,
  to get this working your code required below changes to achieve desired result :
- Order will not be guaranteed in your case, if you want to do it in order, you can use **LinkedHashMap**.

  ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] name = {"(call SP_PKG.GETINFOTYPE(0, 0, 0, 0))"};
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Param1", "Value1");
        params.put("Param2", "Value2");
        params.put("Param3", "Value3");
        System.out.println("Hello");
        params.forEach((k, v) -> {
            name[0] = name[0].replaceFirst("0", v.toString());
        });
        System.out.println(name[0]);


    }
  ```
- because your code will require multiple replacements to get desired result which you can not use same variable to assign multiple times inside lamda expression, because lamda statement required  an **effectively final variable** to be used else it will give you error
- so what you can do you can make the **name** as final array and use inside lamba statementas i mentioned in code example above.

Comment: Thank you gajju_15. This worked for me. Explanation is also very good.

Answer (score 0):

String.replaceFirst doesn't replace the substrings in the `name` String; it returns a new `String` with the modifications. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the first zero with `Value1`, the second one with `Value2`, etc. it won't work.

There is no guarantee that elements will be in an original order during iteration. It's all about **hashing** as you are using a `HashMap`.

> ... This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

see the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

*It seems you don't need this data structure for the task*.

Instead, you can use an `ArrayList`. All elements in it will be ordered while iteration (as you have put them).

```
List<String> valuesForReplacement = new ArrayList<>();
valuesForReplacement.add("Value1");
valuesForReplacement.add("Value2");
valuesForReplacement.add("Value3");
valuesForReplacement.add("Value4");

for (String value : valuesForReplacement) {
   name = name.replaceFirst("0", value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicReference<String> name = new AtomicReference<>("(call SP_PKG.GETINFOTYPE(0, 0, 0, 0))");
        Map<String, String> params = new TreeMap<>();
        params.put("Param1", "Value1");
        params.put("Param2", "Value2");
        params.put("Param3", "Value3");
        params.forEach((key, value) -> name.set(name.get().replaceFirst("0", value)));
        System.out.println(name.get());
    }
```

output:

```
(call SP_PKG.GETINFOTYPE(Value1, Value2, Value3, 0))
```

---

- `HashMap` does not provide ordering and in this case is essential. So I have chosen to use `TreeMap` instead. As map keys are not used you can also use any implementation of `List` interface

You wrote:

> . Is there a way to do this using lambdas instead of writing traditional code that loops through each entry and replaces.

> (key, value) -> name.set(name.get().replaceFirst("0", value))

- This is use of lambda expression. We are providing here implementation for `BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action`. Probably you wanted to use `Steam API`, but there are no need for it. In this case as we are modifying single object.
- Sample code that you have provided doesn't work because `replaceFirst` method returns modified `String` and in your code there is no `name` variable reference reassignment.
- I have also used `AtomicReference<String>`, instead of String for variable `name`, because variables that are modified inside lamdas have to be effectively final (see [JLS §15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2))

> The restriction to effectively final variables prohibits access to dynamically-changing local variables, whose capture would likely introduce concurrency problems.